# get data from activity to service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, sharedpreferences

I have an activity which takes the date from the date picker and sets it in an edit text and as well as saves in shared preference. Now I want this date in the service class.

The following code shows how I save data in shared preference after button click.

```
 mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                editor.putString("Name", String.valueOf(mPersonName.getText()));
                editor.putString("Type", String.valueOf(mType.getText()));
                editor.putString("Date", mDate.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("UserDay", String.valueOf(day));
                editor.putString("UserMonth", String.valueOf(month+1));
                editor.putString("UserYear", String.valueOf(year));

                editor.commit();

                mPersonName.getText().clear();
                mType.getText().clear();
                mDate.getText().clear();

                newDate=pref.getString("Date","");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"userDate"+newDate,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }
        });
    }
```

This is my service class.

```
public class serviceToCheckTheDate extends Service {
    //@Nullable

    CustomerInformation mCstmr=new CustomerInformation();

    String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

    Calendar mCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentMonth=mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int currentDay=mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int currentYear=mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);


   // SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    //final String myDay=pref.getString("UserDay","");
   // final String myDate= pref.getString("Date","");


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        final Handler mHandler=new Handler();
        final int timeInterel=10000;
        final String UserDate=intent.getStringExtra("enteredDate");
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(currentYear==mCstmr.userYear)
                {
                    if(currentMonth==mCstmr.userMonth)
                    {
                     if((mCstmr.userDay-currentDay)<=5){
                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Namsthe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hellow"+UserDate,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("ser on","ser on");
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle("Document Management!");
                mBuilder.setContentText("Hi,One of your document is going to expire");
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                // notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
                mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
                mHandler.postDelayed(this,timeInterel);
            }
        },timeInterel);
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

How to get the newDate to service.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it can possible using two way

1) using intent

> pass data in intent from activity and get intent data in 
>      onStartCommand() method in service

2) you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library

Define events:

```
public static class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

Prepare subscribers: Declare and annotate your subscribing method, optionally specify a thread mode:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

Register and unregister your subscriber. For example on Android, activities and fragments should usually register according to their life cycle:

```
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }
```

Post events:

```
 EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

more details goto [this link](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/)

Comment: what I wrote in activity and in services for intent is that correct.? Or should I add anything extra.

Comment: check out new answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434340/get-data-from-activity-to-service/43807078#43807078

Answer (score 0):

> in Activity

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this,Myservice.class);

   intent.putExtra("Name", String.valueOf(mPersonName.getText()));
   intent.putExtra("Type", String.valueOf(mType.getText()));
   intent.putExtra("Date", mDate.getText().toString());
   intent.putExtra("UserDay", String.valueOf(day));
   intent.putExtra("UserMonth", String.valueOf(month+1));
   intent.putExtra("UserYear", String.valueOf(year));

   startService(intent);
```

> in Service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    String Name=intent.getStringExtra("Name");
    String Type=intent.getStringExtra("Type");
    String Date=intent.getStringExtra("Date");
    String UserDay=intent.getStringExtra("UserDay");
    String UserMonth=intent.getStringExtra("UserMonth");
    String UserYear=intent.getStringExtra("UserYear"); 

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data by using intent.

In Activity:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this,Myservice.class);
  intent.putExtra("Name", mPersonName.getText().toString());
  intent.putExtra("Type", mType.getText().toString());
  intent.putExtra("Date", mDate.getText().toString());
  intent.putExtra("UserDay", String.valueOf(day));
  intent.putExtra("UserMonth", String.valueOf(month+1));
  intent.putExtra("UserYear", String.valueOf(year));
  startService(intent);
```

In Service:

you can get the data in onStartCommand() through intent which you passed from activity.

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String Name=intent.getStringExtra("Name");
    String Type=intent.getStringExtra("Type");
    String Date=intent.getStringExtra("Date");
    String UserDay=intent.getStringExtra("UserDay");
    String UserMonth=intent.getStringExtra("UserMonth");
    String UserYear=intent.getStringExtra("UserYear"); 
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```